# How to disable Writeables in Play 2.6?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play, if you do something like this:

```
Ok("some text")
```

...it will automatically return a 200 text/plain response.

The problem is, I don't want to ever return text/plain responses, and the fact there's a built-in Writeable that converts to text/plain means that sometimes people do it by accident.

Is there a way to disable the `String` to `text/plain` Writeable?

Also, ideally, I would like to only allow certain Writeables, to make sure that we always use the proper paged format in responses. Is there a way to restrict which Writeables are turned on?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify Writable that you want to use

```
val otherStringWriteable = new Writeable[String](
   str => ByteString(str.getBytes(), 
   Some("text/other")
)

Ok("some text")(otherStringWriteable)
```

Comment: I don't want to have import the implicit to every file. The idea is to prevent people from accidentally returning `text/plain`. If they have to import the implicit each time, that won't help.

Comment: Add implicit writeable for String to package object in the root

Comment: If you have some custom base controller class aka [layer supertype](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html), you can put such an implicit there and thus force it visibility.

Comment: @cdmckay, and actually after re-reading the answer I don't think mavarazy came up with the idea of duplicate `implicit`s before you commented about it.

Comment: @SergGr: I assume that it was implied, considering that explicitly having to pass the Writeable each time would be even more likely to be forgotten :) But I think his answer push having a supertype would work.

Comment: Actually, how does this prevent the text/plain Writeable from being used? Is there a way to cancel an implicit?

Comment: @cdmckay the simplest way to cancel an implicit is to explicitly use something different in place of it. You need to be careful with implicits.

Comment: @cdmckay, not to brag bout it, if you look at the name after the comment you may find that the author of the idea about the layer supertype  is me. The only way I know to cancel already visible `implicit` is to add another matching `implicit` into the scope. Then this implicit type becomes ambiguous for the compiler and it can't select one.

Answer (score 1):

A Filter could be a solution for your Problem **if you have Tests for all Interfaces**: [ScalaHttpFilters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters)

Something like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class ContentTypeFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

        result.body.contentType match {
        case Some("text/plain") => // some exception handling / Logging
        case Some("..") => // ok 
          result
        case None => // ..
      }
    }
  }
}
```